# Time complexity of an algorithm - embedded loop

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to solve this algorithm but I'm not sure
here is the code(trying to get the complexity)

```
For (i =0, i<N, i++) {  
    For (j=0, j<i/2, j++)  {   
        S.O.P (“”);  
    } 
}
```

the S.O.P stands for the instructions given to the CPU.

Comment: What do you mean with "solve this algorithm"? What is `S.O.P.` doing here? What have you tried? What is not working?

Comment: It actually depends what are you doing in place of `S.O.P`. So it's better to post the entire thing instead of replacing your logic with `S.O.P`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm trying to find the big O of this code, the S.O.P stands for instructions given to the CPU

Comment: @MohamedKial please try to be clearer, it is really difficult to help with the information you are giving us. Explain the problem from the beginning, including where you got stuck.

Comment: Consider SOP to be the unit, you just need to count the loops.

Comment: I think `S.O.P.` is just an acronym for `System.out.println()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what S.O.P. stands for, but for the sake of the question, I'll suppose it takes a fixed amount of time - O(1).

Therefore, the only thing left is defining the time the `for` loops take to run.

```
for (i =0, i<N, i++) {         // n times 
    For (j=0, j<i/2, j++)  {   // for each time, this runs n/2 times
        S.O.P (“”);            // fixed time O(1)
    } 
}
```

Given that, we can calculate:

```
T(n) = {sum for i from 0 to n} i/2 = (1/2)*(n*(n-1)/2)
T(n) = (n*(n - 1)/4) * O(1) = O(n^2/4) = O(n^2)
```

So the final time complexity would be `O(n^2)` (O of n squared).

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do with your `T(n)=n * (n/2) * O(1)`, but note the exact number of loops is `(n-1)^2/4`, assuming integer floor division both in the question and in this comment. Of course that does not change the final `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you mean `n * (n - 1) / 4`?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog No, I mean `(n-1)^2/4`.